# Can we bound Backend Rails API to Angular 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, api

I was wondering how can we use Rails (especially rails4) as a backend to Angular?
Can we deploy those two in same server?
Can angular2 live in a Rails project?
And lastly; can we turn any rails app to an api ?

Comment: You can. There are a bunch of docs on the web that  will show you how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Yes you can use it as a backend (API first design)
- You sure can deploy them to the same server if setup correctly
- You could also integrate it into your rails app

If you want to go for the API approach there here are some starting points:

- Rails API as part of Rails Core: https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api
- API Standardization project that helps to keep your API well structured: https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources

Comment: Thanks for the answer.So I can't turn a rails app into an API right? (Can't or Shouldn't )

Comment: Yes you can do that. If you ask for opinion on such a thing you will get a lot of answers. In most situations where you are building an "easier" app the effort to built the rails app as just and API and build the frontend in another techology is not worth it. But if you want to built a rails backend that can serve client appilcations like an emberjs-app or an iphone app then you can. Turning an existing project into an API is possible but depending on the complexity it might be harder than starting anew.